# JPQL query for select parent Entity having @OneToMany relation with Child Entity, containing optional search parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, h2, jpql

I have two entities, `Recipes` and `Ingredient`:

`Recipes` looks like:

```
public class Recipes {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Integer serveCount;

    private RecipesType type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipes",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And `Ingredient` looks like:

```
public class Ingredient {
    
        private Long id;

        private String name;

        private Integer count;

        private String unit;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "RECIPES_ID", nullable = false)
        private Recipes recipes;
    }
```

I was asked to implement filtering service with these parameters:

1. Recipes type(Vegetarian, Dairy, Fast food)
2. Number of serving
3. Specific ingredients (either include or exclude)

So I created a `FilterRequestDTO` based on them and implemented my `service` as below:

```
@Override
public ListResponseDTO<RecipesDTO> getFilteredRecipes(FilterRecipesDTO filterRecipesDTO) {
    ListResponseDTO<RecipesDTO> response = new ListResponseDTO<>();
    var temp = repository.findFilteredRecipes(
            Objects.nonNull(filterRecipesDTO.getType()) ? RecipesType.parseRecipesType(filterRecipesDTO.getType()) : null,
            Objects.nonNull(filterRecipesDTO.getServeCount()) ? filterRecipesDTO.getServeCount() : null,
            filterRecipesDTO.getIncludeIngredients().size() > 0 ? filterRecipesDTO.getIncludeIngredients() : null,
            filterRecipesDTO.getExcludeIngredients().size() > 0 ? filterRecipesDTO.getExcludeIngredients() : null,
            PageRequest.of(filterRecipesDTO.getPage(), filterRecipesDTO.getSize()));

    if (temp.isPresent()) {
        response = new ListResponseDTO<>(filterRecipesDTO.getPage(), temp.get().getNumberOfElements());
        for (Recipes recipes : temp.get().getContent())
            response.getData().add(new RecipesDTO().from(recipes));
    }
    return response;
}
```

And it calls my `Repository` method layer which looks like:

```
@Query("select r from Recipes r join Ingredient i on r.id = i.recipes.id " +
        "where (:typ is null or r.type = :typ) " +
        "and (:cnt  is null or r.serveCount = :cnt) " +
        "and (:inc is null or i.name in :inc) " +
        "and (:exc is null or i.name not in :exc)")
Optional<Page<Recipes>> findFilteredRecipes(@Param("typ") RecipesType type,
                                            @Param("cnt") Integer serveCount,
                                            @Param("inc") List<String> includeIngredients,
                                            @Param("exc") List<String> excludeIngredients,
                                            Pageable page);
```

But when I want to filter results with given `includeIngredients` and `excludeIngredients` lists, it does not seem to work.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated!!

***----------> UPDATE <----------***

With help of @Andrey, finally I could change my repository method to :

```
@Query(value = "select r from Recipes r " +
            "where ((:typ) is null or r.type in :typ) " +
            "and ((:cnt)  is null or r.serveCount in :cnt) " +
            "and ((:inc) is null or exists (select 1 from Ingredient i where i.recipes = r and i.name in :inc)) " +
            "and ((:exc) is null or not exists (select 1 from Ingredient i where i.recipes = r and i.name in :exc)) ")
    Optional<Page<Recipes>> findFilteredRecipes(@Param("typ") List<RecipesType> types,
                                                @Param("cnt") List<Integer> serveCounts,
                                                @Param("inc") List<String> includeIngredients,
                                                @Param("exc") List<String> excludeIngredients,
                                                Pageable page);
```

As you can see I have also changed dataType of `Type` and `ServeCount` search parameters to `list<>` to extend the ability to filter my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to return receipt if it contains at least one ingredient requested, the query would be:

```
select r from Recipes r
where (:typ is null or r.type = :typ)
and (:cnt  is null or r.serveCount = :cnt)
and ((:inc) is null or exists (select 1 from Ingredient i where i.recipes=r and i.name in :inc)) 
and ((:exc) is null or not exists (select 1 from Ingredient i where i.recipes=r and i.name in :exc))
```

if the requirement is to return receipt with all ingredients requested, the query would be:

```
select r from Recipes r
where (:typ is null or r.type = :typ)
and (:cnt  is null or r.serveCount = :cnt)
and ((:inc) is null or :inccnt = (select count(1) from Ingredient i where i.recipes=r and i.name in :inc)) 
and ((:exc) is null or not exists (select 1 from Ingredient i i.recipes=r and where i.name in :exc))
```

Comment: Tnx for your help, but I can not understand "count(1)" also it is not acceptable by JPQL , beside this I want to get the recipes with all of its ingredients not the one/ones that are in my lists, because they are not using to request, they are using just for filtering, to get recipes that contains/contains-not some ingredients!!

Comment: @Sobhan `I can not understand "count(1)" also it is not acceptable by JPQ` - that is the same as `count(*)` or `count(i.id)`, if you DB do not understand that (it is valid from JPQL perspective) - try other variants. `they are not using to request, they are using just for filtering` - you need to user either joint fetch: `select r from Recipes r left join fetch r.ingredients ri` or entity graphs: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs, or transactions

Comment: well with your instruction I wrote this,but it does not filter with any parameter,my privious wrong query could filter with Type and ServeCount :)), would you please say my mistakes,  `select r from Recipes r left join r.ingredients ri where (:typ is null or r.type = :typ) and (:cnt  is null or r.serveCount = :cnt) and (:inc is null) or :inccnt = (select count(i.id) from Ingredient i where i.recipes = r and i.name in :inc) and (:exc is null) or not exists (select 1 from Ingredient i where i.recipes = r and i.name in :exc)`

Comment: @Sobhan you believe you have removed irrelevant parentheses, unfortunately, you made a mistake: `A and (B or C)`  and `A and B or C` are not equivalent restrictions.

Comment: perfect, except voting up your helps I cant do anything to appreciate you.... Anyway filtering using Type and Count are working by adding parentheses, but filtering using Inc and Exc list does not work!!! :(

Comment: @Sobhan try to update the Q with information about what you did, what SQL is generated by HBN, etc... investigating via comments is not a good idea.

Comment: @with your help I could write a new query that supports my requirement, please add my updated query to your answer as the third option which is my requirement, then I will accept your answer!!

Comment: @Sobhan your solution does not differ from mine, except you have changed the input. If it were my project I would use another approach.